# Debugger not stopping at symbols inside of rust::build

Tags: debugging, rust, rust-rocket

I'm trying to debug code inside of the rocket::build.mount I am using Clion and have no issues debugging out side of rocket

```
#[launch]
fn rocket() -> Rocket<Build> {
    build().mount("/", routes![game])
}

#[get("/")]
fn game() {
    let boot_flags: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    let boot_flags_refs = boot_flags.iter().map(|s| s.as_str()).collect();

    rs_main::rs_main(boot_flags_refs);
}
```

if I set the break point at boot_flags it never hits the break point

I've tried setting profile.release debug = true and opt-level = 0, I simply want to be able to run breakpoints inside of rocket

Comment: Have you tried debugging without release?

Comment: Yes, I have ran it with out release

Comment: As an easy workaround, you can move the code to a separate function and call it. That should work.

Comment: I was hoping to find a better solution long term, heh

Answer (score 0):

You sure you are running the project in debug mode (?):

- In your `Cargo.toml` file:

```
[profile.dev]
debug = true
```

- In your `Rocket.toml` file:

```
[global]
log_level = "debug"
```

- Now, run your project in debug mode:

```
cargo run --debug
```

Comment: `debug = true` doesn't enable *"debug mode"*. It instructs the compiler to emit debug symbols. I don't know whether this transitively applies to crate dependencies, though, which may be part of the issue.